# i cant insert section break in aspose.word after add header

Tags: c#, aspose.words

after insert header in aspose.word I want insert BreackNewPage
but
Exception occurred when insert section break in aspose.word for .Net
 my Code Is in here:

```
builder.MoveToHeaderFooter(HeaderFooterType.HeaderPrimary);
        Shape shape = builder.InsertImage(dataDir);
        shape.Height = builder.PageSetup.PageHeight - 200;
        shape.Width = builder.PageSetup.PageWidth - 50;        
        shape.WrapType = WrapType.None;
        shape.BehindText = true;
        shape.RelativeHorizontalPositionRelativeHorizontalPosition.Page;
        shape.RelativeVerticalPosition = RelativeVerticalPosition.Page;
        shape.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        builder.InsertBreak(BreakType.SectionBreakNewPage);
```

Comment: Given the `builder.MoveToHeaderFooter`, I am guessing it doesn't like the fact that you are trying to add a section break to a header?

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException

Comment: its true... so thanks  @mjwills

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cursor needs to be inside the "main Story" to be able to insert the requested break. Please see following code:

```
Document doc = new Document();
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
builder.MoveToHeaderFooter(HeaderFooterType.HeaderPrimary);
Shape shape = builder.InsertImage(MyDir + @"aspose.words.jpg");
shape.Height = builder.PageSetup.PageHeight - 200;
shape.Width = builder.PageSetup.PageWidth - 50;
shape.WrapType = WrapType.None;
shape.BehindText = true;            
shape.RelativeVerticalPosition = RelativeVerticalPosition.Page;
shape.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
builder.MoveToDocumentEnd();
builder.InsertBreak(BreakType.SectionBreakNewPage);
doc.Save(MyDir + @"17.11.docx");
```

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple function provided by aspose.word as

```
Document doc = new Document();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder= new DocumentBuilder(doc);
documentBuilder.MoveToDocumentEnd(); //moving cursor to end of page.
documentBuilder.InsertBreak(BreakType.SectionBreakNewPage); // creating new page.
documentBuilder.PageSetup.ClearFormatting(); //clear formatting.
```